# how md-icons are rendered on browser

Tags: css, angular-material2, google-material-icons

I am using material2 and Material icons in my project. I want to know how these named icons are rendered in the browser. I have used

```
<button md-raised-button><md-icon>mode_edit</md-icon></button>
```

and in the browser, If I inspect the element

```
<md-icon class="mat-icon material-icons" role="img" aria-hidden="true">mode_edit</md-icon>
```

Here are the classes that are used

```
.mat-icon {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    fill: currentColor;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
}

.material-icons {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
    direction: ltr;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

but I am not able to understand how these icons get rendered on UI? 
I just know that md-icons are font icons that are vector images. Can someone explain the way it is rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [material icon's documentation](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#using-the-icons-in-html)

> It’s easy to incorporate icons into your web page.

```
<i class="material-icons">face</i> // rendered as face
```

> This example uses a typographic feature called [ligatures](https://alistapart.com/article/the-era-of-symbol-fonts), which allows
>   rendering of an icon glyph simply by using its textual name. The
>   replacement is done automatically by the web browser and provides more
>   readable code than the equivalent numeric character reference

And here is the detailed answer on stackoverflow

[How do ligature icons work in Material Icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44756736/how-do-ligature-icons-work-in-material-icons)

Answer (score 1):

This feature is called ligatures which allows to render icons using name.

you can find more details in below link

https://alistapart.com/article/the-era-of-symbol-fonts

http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web