# Does anyone know how font awesome renders their icons within figma, just by typing the icon name?

Tags: unicode, fonts, font-awesome

The font awesome font if downloaded locally allows you to render icons just by typing the icon names, any idea how it it does that?

For example, typing `home` changes the text to a home icon, if you have the font selected in your Figma or some of the other design tools.

I tried changing the unicode when I generated my icons using icomoon and fontello, but that didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do ligature icons work in Material Icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44925981/10113238) (it does it exactly the same way as Material Icons)

Comment: @Smitop Yup, it does, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so if you use ligatures in icomoon, it works. I created a video about it too. (Not sure if posting the video is allowed, but can remove it if it isn't).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUO_Ql_9vbo